# how to write cronjob

Tags: python, cron

I tried to setup cronjob for python script `erpnext_sync.py` which is in located at `/home/user_name/frappe-bench/biometric-attendance-sync-tool`

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 -c 'from erpnext_sync import main; main()'
```

This cronjob is not working when I am restarting PC and starting Ubuntu or Windows Terminal.

May I know How to run this cronjob every minute, even after restart computer.

Comment: where is  erpnext_sync located on disk?

Comment: Why are you not running the script itself and instead are importing its `main` function into another script?  Does it work if you instead use `* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user_name/frappe-bench/biometric-attendance-sync-tool/erpnext_sync.py` in your cron line?

Comment: Are you sure that all the services required by `/home/user_name/frappe-bench/biometric-attendance-sync-tool` are available when it runs? You could get more control by creating a systemd service,  but that's another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, or startup scripts, or `systemd` scripts, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. Startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.
An easy way is to store the commands in a `bash` script, and execute it from your terminal session, saving the output, then, execute the script from the "other" environment, saving the output. Compare the saved outputs using `diff`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "=== id ===";id
echo "=== set ===";set
echo "=== env ===";env | sort
echo "=== alias ===";alias`
```

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.